# iOS Concatenate const char with int

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c

I have a const char for my sql request. I use sqlite3_prepare, and he needs a const char. But i want to add a int in this char, i have something like this

```
char *select_user = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM User WHERE id =  %d", idUser];
```

But of course in my example it's not correct, because i use NSString, I tried to change select_user in NSString, but after I have a error in my sql_prepare.

So how can we do it with a const char ?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the `NSString` to a `const char *`

```
NSString *select = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM User WHERE id =  %d", idUser];
const char *cSelect = [select cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: Ok, i can't try this atm, but thx :) I will try this evening.

Answer (score 1):

```
char select_user[256];
sprintf(select_user, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE id =  %d", idUser);
```